# OpenMP runs single thread on mac, The thread num is not 0

Tags: c++, macos, clang, openmp

I tried to apply openmp to a for loop, but it seems that only one thread is running while the max_num_thread is 4. Although I have set num_threads to 4, it still didn't work;

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>


int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel for// num_threads(7)
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("thread id:%d\n",omp_get_num_threads());
        printf("thread num:%d\n",omp_get_max_threads());
    }

    printf("thread num:%d\n",omp_get_max_threads());

    //gmp_printf("%Zd\n",result_array[n-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

compiler command:

```
g++ bn_p.cpp -o bn_p.out -lgmpxx -lgmp -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp //actually g++ is clang on mac
```

Comment: Use `omp_get_thread_num()` to get the id of  each thread.  `omp_get_num_threads()` give the number of threads.

Comment: Thank you very much Alain, it's a really stupid mistake.